# http request handling in multiple html pages app cordova

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cordova, httprequest

I've a MPA(Multiple page application). published for Android and iOS. It simply changes the page when user want to navigate to other page(view). All things are working fine. I want to implement some backend sync features. Problem is, I make Ajax request silently in background and user can change page anytime so app can lose reference of Ajax call which is highly important for keeping track of synced data.

Is there any plugin that can make http request on native code level or some other work around.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [cordova-plugin-http](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP), it is a native plugin that executes all HTTP requests on a background thread.

Installation:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-http
```

Example POST request:

```
cordovaHTTP.post("https://google.com/", {
  id: 12,
  message: "test"
}, { Authorization: "OAuth2: token" }, function(response) {
  // prints 200
  console.log(response.status);
  try {
    response.data = JSON.parse(response.data);
    // prints test
    console.log(response.data.message);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error("JSON parsing error");
  }
  }, function(response) {
    // prints 403
    console.log(response.status);

    //prints Permission denied 
    console.log(response.error);
  });
```

Comment: Thing is if the page changes how to keep tack of returned data. 
i.e. Page 1 makes a http request and before getting answer user moves to page 2 than how can I get response on page 2?

Comment: You can save the response in the callback function in e.g. local-storage and then access it on the other page.

Comment: You get it wrong. I can not wait for calls answer. 
App sends request on page 1 and then user moves to page 2. User do not know about Ajax call is being made. Can I receive answer on page 2?

Comment: This proposal would allow the request to continue in the background, but would not allow for JavaScript based processing across multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to do this.  You can use something like the Cordova HTTP plugin to move HTTP requests to the native side, which will continue to execute across multiple pages, but it won't know what to do with the response once the response comes back if the user navigated to another page.

If your processing really is all background and doesn't truly need any JavaScript post-processing, you could try to look into something like the [cordova-plugin-background-download](https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download) - that basically executes a GET request in the background and saves the result where you tell it. It only supports GET, but it can work even if your whole app is put into the background.

If you need post-processing or non-GET requests, you can consider implementing your logic in native code in a plugin (perhaps using one of the HTTP plugins for Cordova to help with the actual network marshalling).

It'd be awesome if Cordova could support something like service workers, and I've been looking into that here and there.  There's an old implementation for iOS but it doesn't seem to work anymore (and may not really be workable without extensive changes): [cordova-plugin-serviceworker](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-service-worker).

One other option would be to make your app a pseudo-SPA with some `iframe`s.  Have an `iframe` doing your requests and processing, and create interaction between the content `iframe` as needed.  But that isn't trivial either.